# Can I use several recommender types in one Mahout project, and combine their results?

Tags: windows, mahout, evaluation

I am trying to implement a recommender system uisng Mahout framework. As I do not have Linux machine, I cannot use Hadoop to deal with large martrix. (The tutorial for installing Hadoop on Windows does not work for me.)

My Users have three types of features, each type contains 5 to 9 features. I wonder whether I can build these features into one FileDataModel, or whether I can process each group of features separately and combine the results.

If the latter one works, then I need to have the UserIds from the previous processing result to create a new FileDataModel for the next group of features. Is it doable?

Here I still have questions for which I have not found answer, hope anyone can help: how many features can Mahout within Windows environment, without Hadoop, handle actually? And how often do we need to re-optimize a system after one algorithm being put in production? Does it work automatically? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well..mahout can run without hadoop if it doesn't find HADOOP_HOME env variable set..On the other hand..I am not sure if mahout can run on Window right away as I didnt find any .bat file or conf for windows...You need to install cygwin for both hadoop and mahout if you want to run them on windows.

It is very similar to the fact how Pig works when HADOOP_HOME is not set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Mahout can run on Windows. I am using Eclipse with Mahout unter Windows 7. It works for small set of features sometimes. I don't know how to install and config all such things. So I just want to use the environment now I have.

Comment: Another thing..i guess item based recommendation needs hadoop..user based or memory based recommendation will not require hadoop..My processing huge data generally item-item recommendation(item based recommendation) is used..which in the underline uses hadoop. From production stand point, type of recommendation, creates a huge difference. Using hadoop, creates a bigger difference as with MapReduce you scale up your processing and will be much faster processing when it comes to huge datasets

Comment: All the algorithms thats uses classes and interfaces from cf/taste/hadoop/* will not work, i guess.

Comment: No, I can use ItemBasedRecommender. Would you please help answer my last two questions "how often do we need to re-optimize a system after one algorithm being put in production? Does it work automatically? " They are now more important for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a huge difference between working standalone and trying out on a cluster..There aren't much things to optimize from mahout's end but you need to optimize MapReduce..things like number of mappers and the jvm size and some other stuff..